# join with exact match value otherwise join with default value

Tags: oracle, join, match

I have a table a

```
 c1   c2    c3    c4     value
all  all    all   all     5
all  david  all   Y       6
all  all    cd    all     7
```

and  table b

```
c1   c2      c3     c4   
a   peter    cd      N    
b   david    all     Y     
c   all      cd      N
```

I want to have get the value from table a into table b, the desired results is like this:

```
c1   c2      c3     c4    Value
a   david    cd      N    5
b   david    ab      Y    6   
c   all      cd      N    7
```

That is use the default "all" value if there is no close match find.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is c2 david and not peter for value 5 in your result. additionally why is c3 ab and not all for value 6 in your result I'm not seeing a pattern on which we could build.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possibilities assuming you have some errors in your example result data. (C2 for value 5 and C3 for value 6 are suspect to me)

1. Use a CTE to union the results replace all with null and use aggregation to get max value
2. Use a Join on value and evaluate table a's value for each c column if it's not `all` use it, otherwise use B's value.  (IF a and b are both all it doesn't matter which we use.) this may be problematic if both values are potentially different like if Value 6 had a Y in A, and a N in B.  but no such example exits in your data so I'm trusting it doesn't happen. (or if it did, picking A's value is more appropriate if it's not all)

AS a cte: (Common Table expression)

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT replace(c1,'all',null)
     , replace(c2,'all',null)
     , replace(c3,'all',null)
     , replace(c4,'all',null)
     , value
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT replace(c1,'all',null)
     , replace(c2,'all',null)
     , replace(c3,'all',null)
     , replace(c4,'all',null)
     , value
FROM b)  
/* We have to eval the max as if it's null we need to replace it with all
   Might be able to avoid the replacing all provided all values of c1-c4 are   
   greater than all...  replacing just seemed safer. at a hit to performance.*/
SELECT coalesce(max(c1),'all') as c1
      ,coalesce(max(c2),'all') as c2
      ,coalesce(max(c3),'all') as c3
      ,coalesce(max(c4),'all') as c4
      ,value
FROM cte
GROUP BY value
```

Using a join (simpler from a maintenance and perhaps performance standpoint)

```
SELECT case when A.C1 <> 'all' then A.C1 else B.c1 end as C1,
       case when A.C2 <> 'all' then A.C2 else B.c2 end as C2,
       case when A.C3 <> 'all' then A.C3 else B.c3 end as C3,
       case when A.C4 <> 'all' then A.C4 else B.C4 end as C4,
       A.value --A.val = b.val so it doesn't matter which se use.
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.value = B.Value
```

Depending on existing indexes and data volume the first approach might be better than the second.